# Countif criteria and range are time values, excel 2016

Tags: excel-formula

I am using Excel for Mac 2016.

I would like to count number of occurrences of time values e.g., 5:00pm in a column (A1:A100000). I would like to count the number of occurrences according to time value criteria in a different smaller column e.g., (B1:B10), which are also times. So I am matching time with time. For each row of the smaller column, I have tried the following:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100000,B1), which returns 0. 

=COUNTIF(A1:A100000,"="&B1), which returns 0.
```

`=COUNTIF(A1:A100000,">="&B1)`, which funnily enough, returns an actual number of occurrences, but is incorrect because I only want it to equal (B3), not be greater than.

Even when I hard code it in:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A100000,">=5:00")` works, `=COUNTIF(A1:A100000,"=5:00")` does not.

Because the time values in (B1:B10) are in serial form, e.g., 5:00pm, 6:00pm etc, even when I try:

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A100000,">="&B1,A1:A100000,"<"&B2)`, it doesn't seem to return a correct value.

It does not seem to matter whether I have the range and/or formatted as Time, or General, nothing works! I'm sure it must be something simple that I am missing.

Comment: Z1: `=Value (B1)`    Try using the Z1 value in COUNTIF now

Comment: It is hard without seeing real data.  Do you mind to post a screenshot and show the actual formula that you are using?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A1:A100000,"="&B1)` works perfectly. As @ian0411 said, please share an example of data as you might be missing something or there are chances that the time format is different in both the columns.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so here is the ACTUAL formula, which looks nothing like the simplified one above. Basic COUNTIFS with Named ranges, and criteria. I have also uploaded a link to a screen shot of formula, and sample file.

=COUNTIFS(Appointment_date,">="&$C$5,Appointment_date,"<="&$C$6,Client_Name,"?*",Status,"Attended; ",Location,"*Richmond",Appointment_Day,C$9,Appointment_time,$B12)/$C$7

Screen shot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_m00iNatJANMWVuWGdLem5Vb1U/view?usp=sharing

Sample of file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_m00iNatJANMnE0UXZyUTctYk0

The real problem appears to be in the formula's inability to recognise specific times in the "Appointment time" column. I have outlined specifics within the document.

Thanks so much!